# How to make this form validation work for custom file upload field

Tags: angular

In the below reactive form I add a red border around the input fields if there is an error. Error is when the fields are left empty and the user clicks submit button or when user focuses on the input fields and move out without entering anything.
See this demo and you will know what I mean (Press tab on input field and it will display red border because you touched it and it was left empty)- https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ynkf5j

The same thing gets tricky when I create a custom upload field where we need to hide the real file input for the sake of customization - DEMO https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fqzszn
The error border is added on the file input when we click on submit without entering anything because there is no touched involved there but the second case `(cForm.controls.file.errors?.required && cForm.controls.file.touched)` doesn't work properly.

I need to find a way to overcome this. Can we make it touched or is there any other way to accomplish this.

```
  <form [formGroup]="cForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
      <input type=text placeholder="name" formControlName="name"
      [ngClass]="{'err-border': (cForm.controls.name.errors?.required && cForm.controls.name.touched) || cForm.controls.name.errors?.required && submitted}" 
      >
      <br><br><br>
      <input type="file" formControlName="file" id="realInput" style="display: none">
      <button id="fakeBtn"
      [ngClass]="{'err-border': (cForm.controls.file.errors?.required && submitted) || (cForm.controls.file.errors?.required && cForm.controls.file.touched)}"
      >Upload</button>
      <span id="text">No file selected</span>
      <br><br><br>
      <button type="submit" >Submit</button>
    </form>
```

TS FILE

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';


@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit  {
  cForm: FormGroup;
  submitted = false;
  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.cForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      name: ['', Validators.required],
      file: ['', Validators.required]
    });
    var realInput = document.querySelector('#realInput');
    var fakeBtn = document.querySelector('#fakeBtn');
    var text = document.querySelector('#text');
    fakeBtn.addEventListener("click", function(){
       // @ts-ignore
      realInput.click();

       })
       realInput.addEventListener("change", function(event) {
       // @ts-ignore
      if(realInput.value) {
         // @ts-ignore
        text.innerHTML = event.target.files[0].name;
      } else {
          text.innerHTML = "No file selected";
      }
       });

  }
onSubmit() {
  this.submitted = true;
  if(this.cForm.invalid) {
    return;
  }
  console.log(this.cForm.value);
}

}
```

Comment: Do you want to set the upload button as required field?

Comment: yes, its already set required

Answer (score 0):

the event which you need is the focus event, at which point we mark the button as touched and your existing validations take over from there... we do this via 2 changes to your code

in your **app.component.ts**, added:

```
focusFunction(){
  this.cForm.controls.file.markAsTouched(); 
}
```

one change to your `#fakeBtn` in app.component.html:

```
<button id="fakeBtn"
  [ngClass]="{'err-border': (cForm.controls.file.errors?.required && submitted) || (cForm.controls.file.errors?.required && cForm.controls.file.touched)}"
  (focus)="focusFunction()"
  >Upload</button>
```

complete [demo from your forked code is here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gork6v?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Comment: The red border also appears when I click the upload button how do i prevent this.

Comment: I have added input type button which the submitted condition to become true https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-m2hmua The red border shouldn't come when you click the upload button.

Comment: `(focusout)` is what we need Thanks for the answer it helped me lead to the solution.